# MS Identity and Access Tool MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, wif, claims-based-identity

This VS 2012 extension is meant to allow me to add a local Development STS to my MVC application http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e

I follow the very simple instructions e.g. Right Click the project name and select Identity and Access in the menu. Select your Identity Provider and the OK to apply the settings to your web.config.

I run my MVC 4 application and it redirects immediately to login.aspx

I'm guessing there are ***special*** instructions for MVC 4.

What are they?

Where do I find them?

*EDIT*

To be clear I have created a ASP.MVC 4 Internet application in visual studio 2012. Then I am using the Identity & Access Tool to add a local development STS to Test my application.

I am running the site on a local IIS Express

When I debug the application I am redirected to

> localhost:11378/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

This occurs even if I remove forms authentication as suggested in advice already given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case I added this

```
<system.web>
...
<httpModules>
...
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>
```

and this

```
<system.webServer>
...
   <modules>
   ...
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

*EDIT*

The next problem you might get is this

> A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   or
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
>   token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
>   configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
>   ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
>   provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
>   it can be configured by setting the static property
>   AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

add these 2 claims to the Development STS in the Identity and Access Tool

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider

and add this line to your Global.asax

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

[This article helped me](http://brockallen.com/2012/07/08/mvc-4-antiforgerytoken-and-claims/)

Answer (score 3):

Removing FormsAuthentication module worked for me.

```
 <httpModules>
    ...
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
 </httpModules>
```

Comment: Just tried this and it also worked for me. Confusing since the auth. mode is set to none.

Comment: needed to remove from modules as well

Comment: @Peter that's what his original answer said, you just misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Dismissile I upvoted it, but it wasn't complete. I put the complete answer in my response.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my MVC4 application on local IIS Express.

It turned out that **Windows Authentication** was enabled for the project. Disabling Windows Authentication (in project properties pane -- **press F4**) fixed the problem.